# Get zip file from url (PHP)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, zip

I have a zip files that I want users to be able to download. The trick is I don't want the users to see what the url is and I don't want to download the file to my server.

So I want users to click a link like this:

```
http://example.com/download/4
```

which server-side accesses my S3 bucket with this url:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/uploads/4.zip
```

I've tried cURL, using S3 methods, and various `headers()` in my `download($file_id)` function but can't get this to work. This has to be easy, right?

Comment: Eveerything you seem to be discussing is still going to involve downloading the file to your server, as far as I can see.  The simple and seemingly-obvious solution is to generate and return a signed URL with a short expiration time to allow the browser to directly download the file directly from S3.  There's no significant difference between possessing a url that's going to expire within a few seconds, and possessing a copy of your file, so if there's some concern on your part about this approach, please explain.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot good point. "the simple and seemingly-obvious solution is to generate and return a signed URL". I agree this is the obvious solution. The issues with your approach is the loss of branding of the url as well as making your bucket structure publicly known. Those are not so important for a hobby site, but for a business they can become real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Xatenev for the help. This is actually what worked for me:

```
$path = '/my-bucket/uploads/4.zip'; // the file made available for download via this PHP file
$mm_type="application/zip"; // modify accordingly to the file type of $path, but in most cases no need to do so

header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
readfile($path); // outputs the content of the file

exit();
```

Comment: Oh - did xou try adding the other headers in again? Maybe it was just the mime_type which was incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

Your right, its quite easy. Probably you will have to write something like this:

```
$path = '/my-bucket/uploads/4.zip'; // the file made available for download via this PHP file
$mm_type="application/x-compressed"; // modify accordingly to the file type of $path, but in most cases no need to do so

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($path)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

readfile($path); // outputs the content of the file

exit();
```

You set various headers to make your user download the .zip. Afterwards you put your file into the output buffer with `readfile()` Afterwards you end your script with `exit()` for security's sake. This should work for you! Remember to change the path to your file.